# Is JRE and JVM the same for Enterprise Edition of JAVA?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jvm

I can imagine JDK to be different at least between JAVA SE and JAVA EE. Are JRE and JVM different too? I researched about this in internet for a longtime and could not find clear answer. It was either only focussed on explaining difference between JDK, JRE and JVM or only the API and functional difference between SE and EE.

I see there are multiple open source server implementations like Tomcat. How are they giving out the JAVA EE jar (servlet-api) ?

Is this even a valid question to think about? Or I have had something misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is that JVM and JRE are the same used for JSE and JEE, to be more clear, what is JEE? JEE is a set of java classes and interfaces and annotations, of course with a container (application server).